# RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8" to [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, out-of-memory

Getting this error intermittently:

> RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read "application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8" to [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

When calling this API:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/blob", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE, produces = {
    MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> imageblob(HttpServletRequest request,
                                                                          @RequestBody byte[] requestPayload) {
try (InputStream imagePayloadStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(requestPayload)) {
    requestHandleService.publishImageBlob(imagePayloadStream, correlationId, cameraId, imageSequenceId);
} catch (IOException e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responseMap, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
return new ResponseEntity<>(responseMap, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Note: requestPayload size is approx 1MB
Note1: using Spring boot 2.6
Note2: publishImageBlob is @Async as below

```
@Service
public class RequestHandleServiceImpl implements RequestHandleService {
    @Override
    @Async
    public void publishImageBlob(InputStream imagePayloadStream(){
        //logic
    }
}
```